# Admob ads showing in app but no impressions showing on in admob interface

Tags: android, admob

I have put out a new android app with admob ads (interstitial) in it and they are working fine on the app. However it has been 24 hours and I am not getting any impressions data (or any other data) for it on the admob website.

Another issue is that after linking my app the icon for my app on the interface is not the actual icon but a general android type icon. I don't know if this has any relevance.

This is the first time I have made a new campaign on the new admob site and don't know whether I have missed something or there is a problem somewhere.

Any ideas.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Can someone tell us what is wrong with AdMob?

Comment: @Hemant I found the only solution was to try a new campaign and that worked fine. I will put a edit to the question with me info (give us a mo to do that).

Comment: I have checked today and now AdMob is showing updated data.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is an issue with AdMob server. Several users are facing the same issue. But this is not unusual. It happens three to four times in a year. Normally this activity take around three days.

Wait for another two to three days. It should be fine.

Comment: I am facing such thing for two days. My clicks/impressions/revenue stopped updating March 29. I know one more user with such problem. I have checked my apps - the ads are working.

Comment: @user3437171 I had left it 4 days and still nothing so I made a new campaign and that worked fine as I put in my edited version.

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes more than 24 hours for all adMob data to be processed and displayed in the web console. So I assume everything is allright, you'll just need to wait 1 more day.

Comment: Ok I will leave another day, if this is all it is I will mark as correct straight away. It has been sometime since I did a new campaign (via the old admob site) but I seem to remember it just took a few hours?

Comment: If I add apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it in admob, will I still get the money for the clicks? I released an app last month, and I realized now, that I didn't monetize it in the actuall admob website. The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it should still be linked to my admob, right? So what does monetizing even do anyway? If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned?

Answer (score 0):

A few tips.

1. Make certain your ID is correct. This is the key step.
2. Look at your logcat when AdMob is running, see if there's anything unusual.
3. Sometimes it takes a day or two. Just try and be patient.

Comment: I added my ID in as 'interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "ca-app-pub-12341.....12");', where I copied and paste the ID from the admob website. I believe I needed the 'ca-app-pub-', is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should be using. Plus AdMob would put an error on the screen if you were using the wrong ad... My guess is that you're just fine, it'll just take a bit to show up.

Comment: If I add apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it in admob, will I still get the money for the clicks? I released an app last month, and I realized now, that I didn't monetize it in the actuall admob website. The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it should still be linked to my admob, right? So what does monetizing even do anyway? If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I added an App before it was on Google Play. I then used the Add Unit ID. When it was eventually listed on Google Play, I manually searched for the App within Admob and linked it - or at least thought I had.

I wasn't receiving any impressions or clicks, so I double checked everything, the Ad Unit ID had changed in AdMob and the only change I made was to manually link the App. So I'm guessing this was where it went wrong. I changed the Ad Unit ID in my app and all working ok now!

Comment: If I add apps to my application, but I don't actually monetize it in admob, will I still get the money for the clicks? I released an app last month, and I realized now, that I didn't monetize it in the actuall admob website. The publisher ID and everything was properly put into my code, so it should still be linked to my admob, right? So what does monetizing even do anyway? If I don't monetize, will I still get the money earned?

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the question of [user1529408](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529408/user1529408)

> Partially Solved
>
> After 4 days still nothing showed up on my impressions so I made a new
>   campaign (hence the partially). To clarify what I did the first time:
>   I had a new app and wanted an ad on it when released. I could
>   therefore not use the search mode as it was not on google play yet. so
>   I had to use add manually mode and then linked it once released.
>
> On the second campaign (the one that works) I was able to use the
>   search mode on admob site to find my app as it was now released. I
>   then had to put this new ad ID into my app and re-release it again
>   with this. This then started to show impressions within a few hours of
>   new version of app appearing in google play.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> As for the icon, that was to do with the size of it was not 128x128.